# How to determine a point's direction on a sinusoidal wave?

Tags: waves

A transverse sinusoidal wave on a string moves from left to right. A snapshot of the wave is shown. Consider the red point on the figure being pointed to by the red arrow. Which way is this red dot moving at this instant?

I thought it's moving up. But the answer is moving down. I don't quite understand. Could anyone explain, please?

[image]

Comment: Indeed it is moving down.

Comment: Yea, but why is it?

Comment: you need to fix a stationary line which passes through the particle and is perpendicular to direction of propagation , as wave moves in right direction , you could see the particle oscillating in the straight line up and down

Comment: Cool! That makes sense.

Comment: Actually the wave stretch and release the string while travelling transversely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$